# django | gunicorn | ImportError: No module named _ssl

Tags: python, django, ssl, python-2.7, gunicorn

Configured and installed python2.7 as below:

```
./configure --enable-shared --with-ssl
make
install
```

And then install gunicorn with command `python setup.py install`.

Installation went well without any problem but now when I am running

`gunicorn django.wsgi:application`

I am getting below error.What should I do to move forward?

```
   Error: class uri 'sync' invalid or not found:

[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/glbdevuser6/glb/portal/aettool/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn-17.5-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/util.py", line 124, in load_class
section, uri)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 378, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2566, in load_entry_point
return ep.load()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2260, in load
entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/glbdevuser6/glb/portal/aettool/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn-17.5-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 12, in <module>
import ssl
  File "/glbdevuser6/glb/portal/aettool/local/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named _ssl
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a Linux distro since you compiled python from source. You need at least 2 SSL library: `openssl` and `openssl-devel`

With Ubuntu: `apt-get install openssl openssl-devel`

With Redhat based: `yum install openssl openssl-devel`

To build from source, you can download from: [openssl](http://www.openssl.org/source/) and [openssl-devel](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=openssl-devel)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't have the liberty to use apt-get or yum,I dont have the root access and the machine on which I am working is not connected to Internet.So, the only option I have is download the source from internet and upload to the machine and then start working on the machine.