# Python gunicorn import error no module named _ssl

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I'm trying to run a Django application using gunicorn as follows

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8088  myapp.wsgi:application
```

However, I get the error in the subject after running the above. I have gone through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767275/django-gunicorn-importerror-no-module-named-ssl) but it doesn't solve my problem since when I drop into a python shell on the same session I can import the `_ssl module` which leaves me confused why the above gunicorn command is not working.

Thank you.

Comment: How did you install gunicorn? Pip, OS package manager, source?

Comment: Through pip install gunicorn

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that,  it's Ubuntu 14.04